# What is the good use to create a wait / notify window with javafx?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, wait

I want to create a popup only once and change the content via the for loop; (for each files dropped). I want to answer yes/no/noAll/yesAll. So I need a wait() just after to show the popup with the first movie content. And if I said "no" for example, I want notify() the thread to be unlock in the aim to reach until the second movie. In this case, The popup content changes with the second movie and I have again a wait() until I answer via the buttons etc.

I tried a lot of things without successfull :/ and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at controllers.HomeController.notifyPopup(HomeController.java:150)
    at controllers.HomeController.lambda$1(HomeController.java:208)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
```

I meet a problem on `dialog.notify()`
Maybe I don't apply the notify() on the same dialog object but it's the case, no ?

Thank you in advance for your help

This is my partial code : Search `// LOOK HERE` in the code to see the main lines

```
public class HomeController {


  @FXML
  private Label home;

  @FXMLViewFlowContext
  private ViewFlowContext context;

  RenameFiles film;
  SimpleBooleanProperty  noAllProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
  SimpleBooleanProperty  yesAllProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
  SimpleBooleanProperty  continuePopup = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
  ArrayList<Path> arrayFile = new ArrayList<Path>();
  Stage stage;
  Boolean firstFile = false;
  JFXDialogLayout content;
  JFXDialog dialog;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() throws FlowException, VetoException {
    Settings settings = (Settings) context.getRegisteredObject("Settings");
    content = new JFXDialogLayout();
    dialog = new JFXDialog((StackPane) context.getRegisteredObject("ROOT"), content, JFXDialog.DialogTransition.CENTER);

    home.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
        if (dragboard.hasFiles()) {
          event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
        } else {
          event.consume();
        }
      }
    });

    // Dropping over surface
    home.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
        boolean success = false;
        if (dragboard.hasFiles()) {
          arrayFile = new ArrayList<Path>();
          success = true;
          noAllProperty.set(false);
          yesAllProperty.set(false);
          dragboard.getFiles().forEach(file -> {
            if(Files.isDirectory(file.toPath())){
              try(Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(file.toURI()))) {
                paths.forEach(filePath -> {
                  if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) 
                  arrayFile.add(filePath);
                });
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              } 
            }else if (Files.isRegularFile(file.toPath()))
            arrayFile.add(file.toPath());

          });
        }
        event.setDropCompleted(success);
        event.consume();

        arrayFile.forEach(file -> {
          film = new RenameFiles(new File(file.toString()), settings);
          if(!noAllProperty.getValue()){
            if(film.getNameWithoutExt().length() > 0){
              if(!yesAllProperty.getValue()){
                    try {
                        firstFile = true;
                        contentPopup();

                        if(firstFile) {
                          dialog.show();
                          dialog.setOverlayClose(false);
                          firstFile = false;
                        }
                 // LOOK HERE
                        waitPopup(dialog);

                    } catch (FlowException | InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }           
              }else{
                film.applyRename(film.getCleanName());
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
  public synchronized void waitPopup(JFXDialog dialog) {
        // This guard only loops once for each special event, which may not
        // be the event we're waiting for.
        while(!continuePopup.getValue()) {
            try {
                dialog.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

  public synchronized void notifyPopup(JFXDialog dialog) {
        continuePopup.setValue(true);
        dialog.notifyAll();
    }

  private void contentPopup() throws FlowException, InterruptedException{

    JFXButton buttonYesPopupRename = new JFXButton("Yes");
    buttonYesPopupRename.setPrefHeight(30);
    buttonYesPopupRename.setPrefWidth(70);
    buttonYesPopupRename.setId("buttonYesPopupRename");
    buttonYesPopupRename.setButtonType(ButtonType.RAISED);
    buttonYesPopupRename.setOnAction(e -> { film.applyRename(film.getCleanName());continuePopup.setValue(true);notifyPopup(dialog); });  // LOOK HERE
    buttonYesPopupRename.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:WHITE;-fx-background-color:#5264AE;-fx-font-size:14px;");

    JFXButton buttonNoPopupRename = new JFXButton("No");
    buttonNoPopupRename.setPrefHeight(30);
    buttonNoPopupRename.setPrefWidth(70);
    buttonNoPopupRename.setId("buttonNoPopupRename");
    buttonNoPopupRename.setButtonType(ButtonType.RAISED);
    buttonNoPopupRename.setOnAction(e -> { continuePopup.setValue(true); notifyPopup(dialog); });  // LOOK HERE
    buttonNoPopupRename.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:WHITE;-fx-background-color:#5264AE;-fx-font-size:14px;");
```

Comment: You need to own the object's monitor for `wait()/notify()`. You don't do that in either of the places. You shouldn't even be trying to use `wait()/notify()` for something like this. How did you come up with this idea?

Comment: Did you happen to search the web for “java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException”?

Comment: @Kayaman,  if I don't do this,  what solution can be used to wait the answer of user about the popup? Maybe I miss something very simple.  I never used the wait and notify,  so I tried to apply  it today.  Me too I don't like this way,   but for the moment I don't see an other way to do that I want  :/.

Comment: @kevincaradant If you've never used `wait()/notify()` then don't start here. You're unlikely to get them right on the first try. They're very low level constructs meant for thread control, but not in this way.

Comment: @Kayaman, Oh ok, I will search a new way to reach to have that I want. Sorry, if I should not have to ask this question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better approach to the problem than your approach:

Make the data about the elements that need to be asked about and the current element available to the event handlers and modify the those values and the UI **when an event occurs**.

Simplified example that let's you choose `Yes` or `No` for some items:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Dialog");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        displayDialog(list.iterator());
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void displayDialog(Iterator<String> iterator) {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Button yes = new Button("Yes");
        Button no = new Button("No");
        Label text = new Label(iterator.next());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(text, yes, no)));
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = evt -> {
            Labeled source = (Labeled) evt.getSource();
            System.out.println("You chose \"" + source.getText() + "\" for \"" + text.getText() + "\"");

            // procede to next state
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                // display next item
                text.setText(iterator.next());
            } else {
                // close "dialog" when no more elements available
                stage.close();
            }
        };
        yes.setOnAction(handler);
        no.setOnAction(handler);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer, it's exactly that I want. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot for this way that seems to me very well !

Answer (score 1):

You have to embed the wait and notify in a syncronized block:

```
synchronized( dialog)
{
    dialog.wait();
}
```

and

```
synchronized( dialog)
{
    dialog.notify();
}
```

BTW: It's enough to just notify(). A notifyAll(() makes only sense if there are more than one thread waiting.

Comment: I already tried your solution but in this case,  my application freezes. I'm surprised because I thought the synchronized block was in a second thread but if all the application is frozen,  that would say it's on the main thread?   I apply your synchronization block in the method waitPopup and notify popup. Should I continue to use the loop while for the wait ?.  It's this part that I don't understand. Thank you in advance

Comment: Since i hardly know FX I don't know in which thread context the GUI callbacks occur. In good old swing it was a separate thread (not the main thread), but all GUI actions happened within the same thread. If FX behaves similar, it's not a good idea to block this thread by a wait function. As Kayaman pointed out in her comment you should look for another way. As far as I know FX is event driven (see your callbacks) so just do the needed action and return. FX framework is waiting for you for the next event.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I edited the question with JAVAFX to be more clear. 
I will check your suggestion.